# Conversion algorithm between colour spaces in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, colors, .net-6.0, color-space

I need all popular colour spaces like RYB, RGB, RGBA, HSL, HSV, CMY, and CMYK.
I've decided to have a base RYB system, which I have to translate to others. I have successfully created an algorithm to do so:

```
public static int[] ryb2rgb(int[] cveta)
{
    double w; double r;  double y;  double b; double g; double myc; double mgc;
    w = Math.Min(Math.Min(cveta[0], cveta[1]), cveta[2]);
    r = (double)(cveta[0]) - w;
    y = (double)(cveta[1]) - w;
    b = (double)(cveta[2]) - w;
    myc = Math.Max(Math.Max(r, y), b);
    g = Math.Min(y, b);
    y -= g; b -= g;
    b *= 2.0; g *= 2.0;
    r += y; g += y;
    mgc = Math.Max(Math.Max(r, g), b);
    if (mgc != 0)
    {
        r *= (myc / mgc);
        g *= (myc / mgc);
        b *= (myc / mgc);
    }
    
    r += w; g += w; b += w;
    return new int[3] {(int)r, (int)g, (int)b};
}
```

I have a similar function that does the opposite.

Could anyone provide the algorithm or say where to get it? Note Hex is not an option, nor is builtins methods. Preferably from RYB to other colour spaces (RGB I've done). If not, I can get to RGB by calling `ryb2rgb` and transforming `that` to different colours. Thank you!

Here is the opposite transformation: RGB to RYB.

```
public static int[] rgb2ryb(int[] cveta)
{
    double w; double r;  double g;  double b; double y; double mgc; double myc;
    w = Math.Min(Math.Min(cveta[0], cveta[1]), cveta[2]);
    r = (double)(cveta[0]) - w;
    g = (double)(cveta[1]) - w;
    b = (double)(cveta[2]) - w;
    mgc = Math.Max(Math.Max(r, g), b);
    y = Math.Min(r, g);
    r -= y; g -= y;
    b /= 2.0; g /= 2.0;
    y += g; b += g;
    myc = Math.Max(Math.Max(r, g), b);
    if (myc != 0)
    {
        r *= (mgc / myc);
        y *= (mgc / myc);
        b *= (mgc / myc);
    }
    
    r += w; y += w; b += w;
    return new int[3] {(int)r, (int)y, (int)b};
}
```

And both functions are fully working

Comment: Are you actually using `[c#-6.0]` as in VS2015, or did you mean to use the `.net-6.0` Tag?

Comment: I meant .net 6.0, didn't know the tag @StefanWuebbe

Comment: If we just give you the code there'll be nothing left for you to do ;)

Comment: No, I have a huge project, this is it’s tiny part